# Is it possible to mix .cs (C#) and .fs (F#) files in a single Visual Studio Windows Console Project? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, f#, console

How to do it?
Is it possible to call a function from one F# code into C# without using a separated dll file or project?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't include two different languages in the same project, but you can merge them using  [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).  To do this, put both projects in the same solution and reference the F# module as you would any dll.  As part of your deployment script, run ilmerge to combine the exe file and dll file into a single exe file.  See this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx) article that details how to use ilmerge to create an exe.

Comment: F#'s static link switch so the same thing as ilmerge.

Answer (score 15):

Not being able to mix C# and F# in the same project creates a problem; It leads to circular dependencies between the two projects. Conceptually there is only one project containing two languages, but because of the way visual studio manages projects languages cannot be mixed, leading to circular dependencies.

For now the only solution I see it to create a lot of interfaces in a third project and have one of the project refer to the interfaces project, instead of the real project.
Is there a better way?

Kind Regards,
Nick

Comment: Excelent comment and question, but you won't get much attention unless you post it as a Question.

Comment: +1 I've seen several commercial projects resort to using ILMerge to get C# and F# into the same assembly. Microsoft should support ILMerge properly and embed it in Visual Studio rather than leaving one employee to put out alpha release software.

Answer (score 12):

No. If you want to produce a single .exe you could use some of the f# static link options use the F# --full-help comandline switch of more details of these.

Answer (score 6):

You can't compile F# source files (.fs) in a C# project, but you can add F# script files (.fsx) which you can use to reference and explore the C# project's assembly from F# interactive:

```
public static class Math
{
    public static double PowN(double d, int n)
    {
        var result = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) result *= d;
        return result;
    }
}
```

F# script file (.fsx):

```
#r "bin\debug\ClassLibrary1.dll"

Math.PowN(2.0,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Compile your F# code, "decompile" with any tool (like reflector, ilspy) to C# code, include it in a project -> Profit!