# How to add f# file to c# class library

Tags: c#, f#, visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to mix .cs (C#) and .fs (F#) files in a single Visual Studio Windows Console Project? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466298/is-it-possible-to-mix-cs-c-and-fs-f-files-in-a-single-visual-studio-wind)

I have a c# class library project. What is the best way to get f# files working in the same project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. You'd need to create these as separate projects. It might however be possible to merge to create a single assembly on build using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en).

Comment: hmm.... ok, any ideas why MS made that not possible?

Comment: When you pick the project you pick its 'type' too (from the visual studio window) presumeably you cant have two languages in one project because it handles their compilation differently and if f# turned up in a c# specified program it wouldnt play nice.

Comment: @Nikos: It may be helpful to remember there is generally a one-to-one correlation between a project and an assembly. And an assembly is created by a _single_ compiler, not multiple compilers working in tandem. That would drastically complicate compilation and tooling support.